# Java crossing generics in class on each other

Tags: java, generics

I have 2 classes with generics on each other. But there is a problem with their parameterizing when they are meeting together. Here are classes:

```
public abstract class AView<T extends IController> {
    protected T controller;
}

public abstract class AController<T extends AView> implements IController {
    protected T view;
}
```

Here, AController should be parameterized as `<T extends AView<AController<T>>>` (but it looks too overloaded?)
And here is parametrizing example:

```
public abstract class AWindowView<T extends AController> extends AView<T> {}
```

AController here should be parameterized, but how? And again, it would be very overloaded. Wildcards also don't recommended.

The reason for this code was to have a reference in classes on each other of their childs. My previous version have only one reference in controller on view, and that realization has only one simple generic. But now I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just program to the interface?  Do you really need the view class to know the type of its controller?

Comment: @Jules maybe it's bug in my MVC architecture: I'm using SWT, my controller has some logic and actions (extends MouseAdapter etc) that connect models and view, view has view components and 'hang' controller's actions on its components (buttons,labels etc). That is why i need a reference on controller. and i also need a reference on view for pushing/getting some data in/from view

Comment: I think you misunderstand my comment: my question is not why the reference is required, but why you just can't use `protection IController controller` in AView, rather than having to know the correct subtype of controller.  Show us some code for why this is necessary, and maybe we can think of a better solution.

Comment: @Jules coz it is an abstract class and it's childs (e.g. EditController, AddController) can has different methods etc...

Comment: Have you considered just having an extra field of the correct type in the subclasses of AView?  Yes, this would be inefficient in memory usage, but for any realistic application the overhead would be small, and the duplication of code is minimal.

Comment: @Jules yes, i have. but i hoped there is more 'elegant' solution =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most general way is to have both view and controller have two type parameters, one for the view and one for the controller. That way, each thing can refer to itself and the other one.

```
public abstract class AView<V extends AView<V, C>,
                            C extends AController<V, C>> {
    protected C controller;
}

public abstract class AController<V extends AView<V, C>,
                                  C extends AController<V, C>>
        implements IController {
    protected V view;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind looking at my question to see if you can answer it? It is based off this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37199687/java-circular-generics-inheritance-class-declaration-dilemma